# Using Range<Index> with NSRange in the NSAttributedString API

Tags: ios, swift, range, nsattributedstring, nsrange

I'm attempting to determine the indexes of occurrences of a given string in a `String`, then generate an `NSRange` using those indexes in order to add attributes to an `NSMutableAttributedString`. The problem is `rangeOfString` returns `Range<Index>` but `addAttributes:range:` expects an `NSRange`. My attempts to create an `NSRange` from the start and end indexes of the `Range` have failed, because `String.CharacterView.Index` is not an `Int`, thus it will not compile.

How can one use `Range<Index>` values to create an `NSRange`?

```
var originalString = "Hello {world} and those who inhabit it."

let firstBraceIndex = originalString.rangeOfString("{") //Range<Index>
let firstClosingBraceIndex = originalString.rangeOfString("}")

let range = NSMakeRange(firstBraceIndex.startIndex, firstClosingBraceIndex.endIndex)
//compile time error: cannot convert value of type Index to expected argument type Int

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalString)
attributedString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: boldFont], range: range)
```

Comment: I don't see you calling `rangeOfString` anywhere. Your code makes no sense. What the heck is `originalString("{")`???? This cannot possibly be your real code; it is nonsense.

Comment: @matt Missed part of it on 2nd and 3rd lines, updated

Comment: My answer remains the same. Where you now have `let firstBraceIndex = originalString.rangeOfString("{")`, say `let firstBraceIndex = (originalString as NSString).rangeOfString("{")`. Now you have an NSRange and can carry on from there.

Answer (score 8):

If you start with your original string cast as a Cocoa NSString:

```
var originalString = "Hello {world} and those who inhabit it." as NSString
```

... then your range results will be NSRange and you'll be able to hand them back to Cocoa.

Comment: And see my book, which goes into this topic in some detail: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_string

Comment: No way to do this with a native Swift String?

Comment: This _is_ the way to do it with a native Swift string. I don't see what you're after. I've solved the problem for you. Do you need me to rewrite your whole code and prove it? Just try what I said.

Comment: It might be the way to do it, but involves bridging. It doesn't *quite* use String, and it definitely doesn't use Swift Ranges. It worked for me, but there's more than a whiff of "workaround" to it. It's perfectly clear what bothers him about the solution; there's no need to be abrasive about it.

Answer (score 4):

To make an NSRange you need to get the starting location and length of the range as ints. You can do this using the `distance(from:to:)` method on your `originalString`:

```
let rangeStartIndex = firstBraceIndex!.lowerBound
let rangeEndIndex = firstClosingBraceIndex!.upperBound

let start = originalString.distance(from: originalString.startIndex, to: rangeStartIndex)
let length = originalString.distance(from: rangeStartIndex, to: rangeEndIndex)

let nsRange = NSMakeRange(start, length)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalString)
attributedString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: boldFont], range: nsRange)
```

To get the startingLocation, get the distance from the `originalString`'s startIndex, to the starting index of the range you want (which in your case would be the `firstBraceIndex.lowerBound` if you want to include the `{`, or `firstBraceIndex.upperBound` if you don't). Then to get the length of your range, get the distance from your range's starting index to its ending index.

I just force unwrapped your `firstBraceIndex` and `firstClosingBraceIndex` to make the code easier to read, but of course it would be better to properly deal with these potentially being nil.